# How do I pass variables from one view to another and render with the last view's URL in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm building a student management system using Django.

In this code, The user search for a student with the encrypted query 
`name=StudentName&grade=Grade&id=StudentID&phone=ParentPhoneNumber&report=StudentReportNumber`,
that is extracted with the `decrypt()` method.

Here are the two methods, the one which process the query and the one which shows the student profile.

No data from the query is saved to the database, but will be used to query the student details from the database.

```
def process_query(request):
    # process the query from the url /?details={{ some hashes here }}

    if request.method == 'GET':
        raw_deatils = request.GET.get('details', None)
        if raw_deatils:
            details = decrypt(raw_deatils)
            # decrypt is a function that is defined
            # in the utils which takes the input string,
            # check predeifined tests to test if valid.
            # and return the decrypted query string else None

            if details:

            # now the decrypted message looks something like this.
            # name=StudentName&grade=Grade&id=StudentID&phone=
            # ParentPhoneNumber&report=StudentReportNumber
            # some more processing pulls out value to variables,

                name = details['StudentName'],
                grade = details['Grade'],
                student_id = details['StudentID'],
                phone = details['ParentPhoneNumber'],
                report = details['StudentReportNumber'],
                search_token = details['token']
                return redirect("somewhere I'm stuck")
            else:
                # encryption error, so redirect user to query page
        else:
            # error with submission redirect to query page
    else:
        # error with method. redirect to homepage.

def student_profile(request, name=None, grade=None, student_id=None):
# token to be added??

    # some data processing to get marks,
    # progress report. etc
    if student_id:
        context = {
            'name' : name,
            'grade' : grade,

            'student_id' : student_id,
            'report' : report,
            'marks': {
                # another dictionary of dictionaries
                # as the product of the processing
            },
            'token' : token,
            'attendance': {
                # another dicitonary of stuff.
            }
    else:

        context = {
            'name' : name,
            'grade' : grade,
        }

    return render(request, 'students/profile/single.html', context)
```

urls for this,

```
url(r'^go/$', 'students.views.process_query' name='process_view'),
url(r'^profile/(?P<name>[a-zA-Z]{1,20})/(?P<grade>[a-zA-Z]{1,20})$',
 'students.views.student_profile', name='profile_view'),
```

whenever `profile_view` is called without 'process_view', the name and grade only should be shown. If the `profile_view` is initiated by the `process_view` the context with attendance and marks should be rendered.

This works till the `process_view` redirect, but I don't have a clue where should i redierect (or even should I redirect? *stuck*) and calling the `profile_view`.

So the summary of the question,

How do I redirect from `process_view` to `profile_view` without losing data collected in `process_view` to the `profile_view` and render the content with the url of `profile_view`?
I don't want the `token` and `student_id` to be shown on the url.

Thanks for any suggestions/help.

Answer (score 20):

**To access the `token` and `student_id` variables in `profile_view`, you can use [`request.session`.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views)**

In your `process_view`, set `token` and `student_id` in the session.

```
def process_view(..):
    ...
    request.session['token'] = token # set 'token' in the session
    request.session['student_id'] = student_id # set 'student_id' in the session
    ..
```

Then in your `profile_view`, you can access these 2 variables from the session. You don't need to pass those 2 variables in the URL then.

```
def profile_view(..):
    ...
    token = request.session['token'] # get 'token' from the session
    student_id = request.session['student_id'] # get 'student_id' from the session
    ..
```

You can set other variables also in the session which you might need in `profile_view`.

Comment: this works, but note that the values will stay there in the session until they are reset... they're not being reset after e.g. the page got loaded

Comment: @gevra Yes, the values will stay in the session. You can delete it manually, after you consume the session value if you need so.

Comment: true, just thought it's important to mention it...
`request.session.pop('token', None)
request.session.modified = True` 
will do the trick

Comment: Hi @gevra I know it's a bit late, but what exactly does `request.session.modified = True` do?

Comment: from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved)... "By default, Django only saves to the session database when the session has been modified – that is if any of its dictionary values have been assigned or deleted"

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It works for me. I used it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72035579/download-to-csv-the-result-of-a-search-in-django

Answer (score 0):

Do not think views, think code

```
def _student_profile(*arg_data, **kwarg_data):
    context = do(arg_data, kwarg_data)
    return render("my_template", context)


def student_profile(request, name=None, grade=None, student_id=None):
    data = do_things(request)
    data.update({"name": name, "grade": grade, "student_id": student_id})
    return _student_profile(**data)


def process_query(request):
    data = do_other_things(request)
    return _student_profile(**data)
```

Comment: Nice philosophy but what's your point?

Answer (score 0):

All other solutions are respectable, but this is a more easy approach and beginners can better understand this. Most beginners don't reach the level of "Sessions" like myself. So, a more straightforward approach is to use Django forms and post requests.

Let's say we're trying to duplicate cart functionality and are trying to gather selected posts on the orders page. So, we simply write a form as follows:

```
class SelectForm(forms.Form):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    select = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        queryset=products
    )
```

Then render the form on the display_products page like this.

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'cart' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
</form>
```

Notice the **action attribute** where it is sending the data to the **cart view**. Next, on the order view, we do something like the following:

```
def order(request):
    form = SelectForm()
    products = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SelectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=form.cleaned_data['select'])
            print(products)


return render(request, 'data/cart.html', {'products': products})
```

After that when you visit the cart page or whatever you may call it, you'll see the list of **selected products** over there.

This example may not fit your problem, but I think the genre is the same and can at least give you a hint on how to achieve the transfer f data from one view to other.
If you find any mistakes, I'll be glad to know.