# Accessing variables from other methods in a django app

Tags: python, django

I am quite new to django and python, and I have an issue using methods and define them properly. 
I would like to store calculation in a method .. and call that method in another method here is how it looks :

```
def get_info_array(self, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
    current_response_list = get_current_team(self)
    member_info_array = []
    for response_dic in current_response_list:
        current_response = list(response_dic.values())[0]
        chunk_score = get_chunk_score3()
    print(chunk_score)
    return chunk_score


def get_chunk_score3(self, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
    answer_question1 = current_response.answers.get(question_id = 2)
    answer_question2 = current_response.answers.get(question_id = 3)
    json_answer_question1 = json.loads(answer_question1.body)
    json_answer_question2 = json.loads(answer_question2.body)
    answer_key_question1 = list(json_answer_question1.keys())[0][0]
    answer_key_question2 = list(json_answer_question2.keys())[0][0]
    if answer_key_question1 == "1" or "3":
        score1 = list(json_answer_question1.values())[0]
    else:
        score1 = -list(json_answer_question1.values())[0]

        if answer_key_question2 == "1" or "3":
            score2 = list(json_answer_question2.values())[0]
        else:
            score2 = -list(json_answer_question2.values())[0]

            chunk_score = math.ceil((score1+score2)/2)
        return chunk_score
```

when I try to run that code I get that in current_response in get_chunk_score3 is not define, how can I access variable from other methods ?

Any tips is well welcome to progress.

edit: 
complete code :

```
class EmployeeChartData(APIView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    http_method_names = ['get',]

    #authentication_classes = []
    #permission_classes = []
    #serializer_class = MyUserSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializer_class



    def get(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):

        chunk2 = get_chunk_score2(self)
        info2 = get_info_relationship2(self)
        rep_system2 = get_rep_system2(self)
        reality = get_reality_structure2(self)
        scenario = get_scenario_thinking2(self)
        percept = get_perceptual_category2(self)

        data = {

            "chunk2":chunk2
        }
        return Response(data)

    def get_current_team(self, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
    current_team_member = Project.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all()
    members_response_list = []
    for member in current_team_member:
        member_id = member.id
        member_response = get_user_response(member_id)
        members_response_list.append({member_id:member_response})

    return members_response_list

def get_user_response(member_id):
    current_user = MyUser.objects.get(id = member_id) #current_user
    survey_team = Survey.objects.get(name= 'Survey SoftScore') #survey team (to change to final one)
    current_response = ResponseModel.objects.filter(user = current_user, survey = survey_team)[0]

return current_response


def get_info_array(self, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
                current_response_list = get_current_team(self)
                member_info_array = []
                for response_dic in current_response_list:
                    current_response = list(response_dic.values())[0]
                    chunk_score = get_chunk_score3()
                    print(chunk_score)
                    return current_response_list
def get_chunk_score3():
            answer_question1 = current_response.answers.get(question_id = 2)
            answer_question2 = current_response.answers.get(question_id = 3)
            json_answer_question1 = json.loads(answer_question1.body)
            json_answer_question2 = json.loads(answer_question2.body)
            answer_key_question1 = list(json_answer_question1.keys())[0][0]
            answer_key_question2 = list(json_answer_question2.keys())[0][0]
            if answer_key_question1 == "1" or "3":
                score1 = list(json_answer_question1.values())[0]
            else:
                score1 = -list(json_answer_question1.values())[0]

                if answer_key_question2 == "1" or "3":
                    score2 = list(json_answer_question2.values())[0]
                else:
                    score2 = -list(json_answer_question2.values())[0]

                chunk_score = math.ceil((score1+score2)/2)

            return chunk_score
```

Comment: store it to database, and retrieve from the database in the next view

Comment: another way is to save it in the session, read up here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31707946/8150371

Comment: Does this code live inside a class? Are the functions on the same .py file?

Comment: @guillermo nop the code does not live inside a classe but are on the same view.py file

Comment: Where and how do you call the methods? Also, *self* is used within the scope of a class abject, not single methods.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Hi, I have added all the code for you to have a look, in the end what I would like to achieve is to have multiple calculation method and in the end get a list of all those calculation

Comment: @Ben2pop The new code is not well indented, it happens on copy paste to SO. `get_chunk_score3():` is inside the class or not? if it is when you call it (inside the class) you must do it `self.get_chunk_score3()`

Comment: you should read on scope of [variables in python](https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/global_scope.html)

Answer (score 0):

I assume entire code is part of the `EmployeeChartData` class.

`current_response` is not defined anywhere in the class. You have a method `get_user_response()` which returns `current_response` so you either have to call `get_user_response()` and assign returned `ResponseModel` object to `current_response` variable in `get_chunk_score3()` or change `get_user_response()` to assign object to a class variable.

I guess the simplest solution would be using by class variable. You create `current_response` and then use it throughout the class:

```
class EmployeeChartData(APIView):
    current_response = None # Default

    def get_user_response(self, member_id):
        current_user = MyUser.objects.get(id = member_id) #current_user
        survey_team = Survey.objects.get(name= 'Survey SoftScore') #survey team (to change to final one)
        self.current_response = ResponseModel.objects.filter(user = current_user, survey = survey_team)[0] # You assign ResponseModel object to current_response class variable

    def get_chunk_score3(self):
        answer_question1 = self.current_response.answers.get(question_id = 2)
```

I don't really see how your class could work, but this is the basic idea of class variables. I also suggest you do a little research on [class and instance variables](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing the problem with the scope of variable `current_response`
You can achieve this in different ways:
Let's say both methods are in same class then you can follow the way suggested by @Borut.

But as seen in your code(detail version) your method `get_chunk_score3()` is not marked as staticmethod and not contains `self`; so I presume that your method is not part of class but in same file.

So you can just define a global variable named `current_response` as follows:

```
# imports
current_response = None
class myClass(object):
    # ... class methods and/or variables
    def get_info_array(self, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...your operations
        current_response = get_current_team(self) # this will assign value to global variable current_response 

def get_chunk_score3():
    # ... here you can access global value of current_response
```

read on scope of [variables in python](https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/global_scope.html)

Note: even if you are using class you can use [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881395/in-python-what-is-a-global-statement), but if you are not going to use it out of the scope of class then you should only define it within class