# reading a variable outside the function

Tags: python, django

I am trying reading an in memory file like this:

```
sttr=request.FILES['file_field'].read()
```

Now I want `sttr` to run unless the website is closed or for a specific time . I can't make it global coz it arise in a situation of data breach I don't want to store it in a database just read it and store it in a variable and pass that variable to another function in views.py and I can't use sessions coz I don't have specific `key` for `session[key]`. Is there any other way to either fetch data from inmemory file from another views.py for example

```
def mainpage(request):
     sttr=request.FILES['file_field'].read()

def hh(request):
     print(sttr)
```

without making `sttr` global?

Comment: What do you mean you don't have specific key for `session[key]`? this sulotion is exactly what you need you set `sttr` like this `request.session['sttr'] = sttr` to the session and access to it in another view with `request.session['sttr']`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31707946/1033510

Answer (score 1):

To share some data between requests, you must store it somewhere and be able to retrieve it one way or another. You **cannot** use globals for this indeed (not in wsgi app at least) since one wsgi process serves more than one user (so user2 data would overwrite user1 data) and you usually have at least half a dozen server process (and I'm talking about a single-server setup here) so any of them could serve a given user's "next" request so you'd end up setting the global in one process and trying to read it in another one - which obviously cannot work since variables are per-process.

That's why someone invented cookies and session - to share more-or-less volatile data between requests.

If your file size is small (I mean *small* - a couple kilobytes or so max, and preferably less), you can just store it's content in session - your mention of "I can't use sessions coz I don't have specific key for session[key]" is complete non-sense, Django's `request.session` object is a dict-like and you can set whatever key you want, else it would be totally useless.

If it's anything bigger, you'd rather want to write the file's content at known place in the filesystem and store the path in the session instead (sessions are loaded in memory, you don't want to clobber your server's ram with gigabytes of  user contents).

Comment: what if the file contains 2,00,000 characters ? do i need to save it

Comment: Check how many ram it uses once loaded in memory and use your own judgment. Just remember that once in production your django project will have to serve quite a few concurrent users...