# How can i send a variable value in same views. django python?

Tags: python, django

I'd like to make a OAUTH login with NAVER.

How can i send a variable(below code: state) value in same view(def naver_login to def naver_callback) with django python?

```
def rand_str():
    return "".join([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(7)])


def naver_login(request):
    client_id = os.environ.get("N_CLIENT_ID")
    redirect_uri = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/login/naver/callback"
    state = rand_str()
    return redirect(
        f"https://nid.naver.com/oauth2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&state={state}"
    )

def naver_callback(request):
    state = request.session.get("state")
    print(dir(request))
    callback_state = request.GET.get("state")
    print(callback_state)
    ...
```

print result is **NULL** and some random char like : **SAG3ra4**

Comment: The callback is usually called by the browser when the authentication has happened.

Comment: I know but i need to compare my state variable and callback state value when i try callback.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707546/how-do-i-pass-variables-from-one-view-to-another-and-render-with-the-last-views this is suit for me.

Comment: You are never setting the session variable you are reading.